# Display NSArray at specific intervals

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` that I would like to display each object at a specific time interval, for example:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];
```

and output it:

```
for (object in array) {
     NSLog(@"%@", object);
     // wait 3 seconds then show next object
}
```

so it should do this:

```
foo 
... wait three seconds 
bar
... wait three seconds
baz
... wait three seconds
repeat
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use Blocks...

You can explore how to do this with a Blocks using third party categories such as : 
https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit

As for a solution without blocks:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger iteration;

- (void)awakeFromNib //Or equivalent method called when you want to start scheduling..
{
    self.myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];
    self.iteration = 0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3  
             target:self
             selector:@selector(fireEvent) 
             userInfo:nil 
             repeats:YES]; //Will Fire every 3 seconds...
}

-(void)fireEvent
{
     NSLog(@"%@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:self.iteration]);
     self.iteration++;
     if (self.iteration>=self.myArray.count) self.iteration=0;
}
```

If you with to invalidate the timer after all elements from the array are shown. Do the following :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib //Or equivalent method called when you want to start scheduling..
{
    self.myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];
    self.iteration = 0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3
             target:self
             selector:@selector(fireEvent:)
             userInfo:nil
             repeats:YES]; //Will Fire every 3 seconds...
}

-(void)fireEvent:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSLog(@">>>> %@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:self.iteration]);
    self.iteration++;
    if (self.iteration>=self.myArray.count) {
        self.iteration=0;
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

NOTE: The latter code only adds a ':' to the @selector(fireEvent:). And reads the NSTimer reference in the fireEvent as a parameter.

Comment: The `scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval:...` method automatically adds the timer instance to the run loop, so you shouldn't call `addTimer:forMode:` yourself.

Comment: NOTE: the @property .... Should go either in your header file (.h) on the top part, or in the implementation file (.m) where you define private properties....

Comment: This might work (remove the extra `=` in `self.myArray`, and eliminate `count-1` in `fireEvent`), but how do you stop the loop? thanks

Comment: Also, be sure to invalidate the timer in the callback method.

Comment: You don't need to store a reference to the timer; just invalidate it in the callback method.

Comment: @KikoLobo You should add the material from your comments to your answer.

Comment: @KikoLobo Change the signature of the callback method to take an instance of `NSTimer` its argument. That will eliminate the need for the additional property.

Comment: Improved.... Any other comments? ... If anyone feels like this is a good answer... Appreciate the vote up... And if this was your question.. Appreciate the correct answer mark :)

Comment: Other than changing `return YES` to `return` this works well :) I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has an answer. thanks very much for the example.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary call to `addTimer:forMode:` and fix the return value and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: All Done... It's now tested in XCODE too.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the surrounding context, you might be able to do what you want by letting an `NSRunLoop` run for 3 seconds.  Alternatively, and perhaps a bit safer and saner, you could use an `NSTimer` to run an action every 3 seconds.

I'd originally suggested breaking up the loop, logging the first element, then perform the same action on the rest of the array after a 3-second delay, using either something like `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or `dispatch_after`, but as [danielbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144632/danielbeard) pointed out, `NSTimer` provides a much more straight-forward way to cancel the action (cancellation is possible with the other methods, but requires planning and manual work).

---

***Edit***: If I were going to do this with an `NSTimer`, I'd probably use [this NSTimer+Blocks category](https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks) and do something like (untested code):

```
__block NSUInteger index = 0;
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 block:^{
     NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
     index++;
     if (index >= [array count]) {
         [timer invalidate];
     }
} repeats:YES];
```

Comment: An `NSTimer` is a better solution, given that a timer can be cancelled, other methods cannot.

Comment: @danielbeard: Yep, good point—are you going to answer, or do you mind if I incorporate that into my answer?

Comment: Incorporate it for sure.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of NSTimer? I'm treading unfamiliar waters, thanks

Comment: @LisaStevens: I've added a rough example—it's untested code, but probably enough to give you an idea of how it'd work.